# golffs - Implement a FUSE filesystem

Tags: code-golf, file-system

Implement a [FUSE filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) in minimum bytes.

Your program must do three things:

- Mounting the virtual filesystem to a directory
- Handling requests to enumerate files in that directory (showing one file)
- Handling requests to read the file in that directory

Rules:

- `ls` (a system program, you don't need to implement it) must show `hello.txt` file (other unrelated files can also be visible, as well as errors may be printed). `hello.txt` must be exact, `68 65 6c 6c 6f 2e 74 78 74` in hex).
- `cat` (a system program) pointed to the file should output `Hello, world.` (punctuation, case and end of lines may differ. A bunch of zero bytes can also slip unnoticed). It can also be `cat m/hello.txt; echo` if there is no trailing newline.
- It must be actual FUSE filesystem, not just a regular file created by your program. For example, freezing your program should freeze the `hello.txt` file (`cat` and `ls` would hang). Creating a socket instead of mounting FUSE filesystem isn't an allowed workaround. Your mounted filesystem should be visible in `/proc/mounts` (or platform analogue).
- For 200 bytes penalty, you may depend on libfuse or use it's header files (or depend on the appropriate FUSE binding in some other language)
- Detaching is optional
- You program may be platform-specific. Somebody else on that platform should check and write a comment that it works (or not)
- Your program can't be a kernel module (`fuse.ko` is the involved kernel module on Linux and is considered a part of environtment, not your program)
- Your program can access `/dev/fuse` (or platform analogue) directly. It may require root access (or changing permissions) for it if needed. It can also rely on `fusermount` for the mounting step (like the example below). Whether using `fusermount` for mounting carry penalty or not I have not decided yet (because of I don't know implementation details enough): if the rest feels like talking to kernel directly then it should not be a problem.
- Additional compilation and invocation parameters are added to the score. A directory to be mounted may be specified as a free (non-penalty) parameter or may be just hardcoded (like `m`)

Example (directly based on official [hello.c](https://fossies.org/dox/fuse-2.9.4/hello_8c_source.html)):

```
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26

#include <fuse.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static const char *hello_str = "Hello, world\n";
static const char *hello_path = "/hello.txt";

static int hello_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)
{
    int res = 0;

    memset(stbuf, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
    if (strcmp(path, "/") == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 2;
    } else if (strcmp(path, hello_path) == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFREG | 0444;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 1;
        stbuf->st_size = strlen(hello_str);
    }
    return res;
}

static int hello_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
             off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    filler(buf, hello_path + 1, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}

static int hello_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    return 0;
}

static int hello_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
              struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    size_t len;
    (void) fi;
    if(strcmp(path, hello_path) != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    len = strlen(hello_str);
    if (offset < len) {
        if (offset + size > len)
            size = len - offset;
        memcpy(buf, hello_str + offset, size);
    } else
        size = 0;

    return size;
}

static struct fuse_operations hello_oper = {
    .getattr    = hello_getattr,
    .readdir    = hello_readdir,
    .open        = hello_open,
    .read        = hello_read,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &hello_oper, NULL);
}
```

```
$ gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 golffs.c -lfuse -o golffs
$ ./golffs  m     # uses fusermount under the hood
$ ls m
hello.txt
$ cat m/hello.txt 
Hello, world
$ fusermount -u m
```

Score of the example: 1974 + 29 (compilation parameters) + 0 (invocation parameters) + 200 (penalty) = 2203

Comment: "hello.txt must be exactly *this hex*" seems to collide with the next line "cat should output Hello, world. **punctuation, EOL and case *may differ***"

Comment: The first is about the virtual file name, the second is about virtual file content. The former is exact, the latter should match `/^hello,?\s?world[.!;?]?\r?\n$?/im` (for example).

Comment: Ohh, okay. I like this challenge because it gives real, non-golfing languages a chance; it will be a while before I have something that works.

Comment: Wait, why are `cat` and `ls` builtins for the filesystem? shouldn't they be standalone binaries?

Comment: `cat` and `ls` are assumed to be system binaries. They are used to test the filesystem. They are clarified because of for poorly behaving filesystems, using other programs (like `dd` and `find`) can lead to different results (due to different syscalls or reaction to them).

Comment: So we get a 200 byte penalty if we use the actual library, which is a kernel module (because in order for a filesystem to show up in `/proc/mounts` or have `udev` even sneeze at it, it needs to have some sort of kernel bus, specifically a module) but we also aren't allowed to make a kernel module, so we have to use the existing library ( on *ix, at least ) which means for Mac and GNU/Linux the 200 byte penalty is unavoidable.

Comment: The `fuse.ko` kernel module is considered part of the system (like kernel or C library). The `libfuse.so` library is considered part of your program. To avoid penalty, you should implement it on low level (on the level the `libfuse.so` itself is implemented), i.e. open `/dev/fuse` and use it. `fusermount` program may be used to get access to `/dev/fuse` without requiring administrator access (assuming it does not take part in filesystem activity after starting up).

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <strike>1348</strike> <strike>998</strike> <strike>846</strike> <strike>748</strike> <strike>714</strike> <strike>683</strike> <strike>642</strike> <strike>575</strike> 520 + strlen("perl -mFuse") + 200 penalty for Fuse.pm = 731 bytes

Was interesting diversion from usual golf challenges.  Started life as a version of https://metacpan.org/source/DPATES/Fuse-0.16/examples/example.pl before getting stripped down.

```
%k=('hello.txt'=>{});sub f{$_=shift;s,^/,,;return$_}Fuse::main(mountpoint=>$ARGV[0],getattr=>sub{$c=f(shift);$c=~s,^/,,;$c=~s/^$/\./;return(exists($k{$c})?0:-2,0,$c eq'.'?16877:33261,1,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1024,0)},getdir=>sub{return(keys%k),0},open=>sub{return(0,[rand()])},statfs=>sub{return0},read=>sub{$c=f(shift);($x,$z,$h)=@_;return-2 unless exists($k{$c});if(!exists($k{$c})){$u=fuse_get_context();return sprintf("pid=0x%08x uid=0x%08x gid=0x%08x\n",@$u{'pid','uid','gid'})}return$z==12?0:substr("Hello, world",$z,$x)})
```

Long lines, but if presented via `fold`, appears as below:

```
# fold foo.pl
%k=('hello.txt'=>{});sub f{$_=shift;s,^/,,;return$_}Fuse::main(mountpoint=>$ARGV
[0],getattr=>sub{$c=f(shift);$c=~s,^/,,;$c=~s/^$/\./;return(exists($k{$c})?0:-2,
0,$c eq'.'?16877:33261,1,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1024,0)},getdir=>sub{return(keys%k),0},o
pen=>sub{return(0,[rand()])},statfs=>sub{return0},read=>sub{$c=f(shift);($x,$z,$
h)=@_;return-2 unless exists($k{$c});if(!exists($k{$c})){$u=fuse_get_context();r
eturn sprintf("pid=0x%08x uid=0x%08x gid=0x%08x\n",@$u{'pid','uid','gid'})}retur
n$z==12?0:substr("Hello, world",$z,$x)})
#
```

Example use:

```
# perl -mFuse foo.pl m &
[1] 6410
# ls -ld m
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 m
# cd m
# ls -l
total 0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12 Jan  1  1970 hello.txt
# cat hello.txt
Hello, world#
```

Comment: Works (although there is lot of room for golfing). Shebang (`#!/usr/bin/perl`) can be moved to invocation `perl foo.pl m`.

Comment: For more interesting diversions, see [my other challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7773/vi?tab=questions&sort=votes).

Comment: Updated source also works, `score = 575 + strlen("perl -mFuse") + 200 = 786`.

Comment: Are you aware that you don't really need to provide `.` and `..` entries?

Comment: Good point, shaved a few more bytes